# How to Manage Blocks with this situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am implementing helper classes for the Instagram API.

I have a method to get the access code:

```
-(void) makeAuthenticateRequestWithBlock: (completionBlock) block {
  if (![self.viewController.view.subviews containsObject: self.webView]) {
    [self.viewController.view addSubview: self.webView];
  }
  if (!self.isUserAuthinticated && self.isAvailableAllRequredData) {
    NSString * fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+basic+public_content+follower_list", KAUTHURL, self.clientId, self.redirectURL];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: fullURL];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [self.webView loadRequest: request];
    self.block = block;
  }
}
```

Where `typedef void(^completionBlock) (BOOL success);` is a block and I have:

`@property (copy, nonatomic)     completionBlock         block;`

In a webview delegate method.

```
-(BOOL) webView: (UIWebView * ) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest * ) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
  NSString * urlString = [
    [request URL] absoluteString
  ];
  NSLog(@ "URL STRING : %@ ", urlString);
  NSArray * UrlParts = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@/", self.redirectURL]];
  if ([UrlParts count] > 1) {
    // do any of the following here
    urlString = [UrlParts objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSRange accessToken = [urlString rangeOfString: @ "#access_token="];
    if (accessToken.location != NSNotFound) {
      NSString * strAccessToken = [urlString substringFromIndex: NSMaxRange(accessToken)];
      NSLog(@ "access token = %@ ", strAccessToken);
      [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
      [
        [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: strAccessToken forKey: kAccessToken
      ];
      [
        [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize
      ];
      self.isUserAuthinticated = true;
      self.block(true);
    }
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

All working fine.

Now when I send a request to the Instagram API I check if a user is authenticated.

```
-(void) getInformationOfOwnWithCompletionBlock: (dataTaskBlock) block {
  if (self.isUserAuthinticated) {
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@self/?access_token=%@", kUSERURL, [
      [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: kAccessToken
    ]];
    [self makeRequestToServerWithUrl: urlString completionBlock: ^ (NSDictionary * data, NSError * error) {
      if (!error) {
        block(data, error);
      } else {
        block(nil, error);
      }
    }];
  } else {
    [self makeAuthenticateRequestWithBlock: ^ (BOOL success) {
      [self getinformationofOwnFollowsWithCompletionBlock: block];
    }];
    // block(nil,errorMsg);
  }
}
```

It will send a request and construct the webview with the returning block. All this is working fine. But when I call same method for two times I get the below error message:

```
[self.instagramVC getInformationOfOwnWithCompletionBlock: ^ (NSDictionary * data, NSError * error) {
  NSLog(@ "%@", data);
}];
[self.instagramVC getInformationOfOwnWithCompletionBlock: ^ (NSDictionary * data, NSError * error) {
  NSLog(@ "DATA 2%@", data);
}];
```

It returns the block of the last called method like output would be DATA 2. I know the reason, it is because `self.block`. So please give me a suggestion so that I don't have to use the global block for each and every request.

Comment: It is quite hard to follow your code, but why are you saving the block in a property?  Why not just pass it through as a parameter to any function that needs it ?

Comment: because when i request for authentication  , it request webview to load request so i need to wait till it complete that request , and return it from there. @Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

As you say, your problem is that you're using a global block for all your requests. You need to set up a data structure to hold info about each pending request. Perhaps a mutable array of dictionaries where each dictionary contains the request and the completion block for that request. Then when a request finishes, match the request with your array of requests, and execute the appropriate completion block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can i manage index of array , i mean request is async so how can i identify index of that block can you give simple example

Comment: There are lots of ways you could handle this. You should be able to save the request and the block at each entry in your array. Then when a request completes, find that request in the array and then execute the corresponding block. No, I don't have an example handy.

Comment: You can also save your completion blocks in a dictionary with the URL as the key, and then look up the completion block using the URL from the completed request.

Answer (score 0):

You use one global block for different requests. Make this block with local scope and your requests get own completions.

Comment: thanks for your answer as i mentioned , it is impossible to make global object for each request because there is n number of request to be done probably  , so it is not good idea.

Comment: 1. Remove property completionBlock.
2. If you want to have completionBlock in heap you can use copy for it.

Comment: if i remove property then how can i return block from webview delegate ?

Comment: Oh, I saw...
Please, look at these two lines in 'makeAuthenticateRequestWithBlock': [self.webView loadRequest: request];
self.block = block;
Your request starts early than assign self.block